# Using Junit5 in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5

hello I have an issue about using Junit5 in IntelliJ. 
I was using it without any problem but after install Intellij Ultimate I get an issue.

[projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpWXc.png)

[project structrue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFitW.png)

I already added junit5.4 to classpath but code is saying 'add junit5 to classpath'
All it does is just adds junit5 to classpath more and more
and nothing's changed.

what should I do?

Comment: JUnit 5 has many different parts that should or should not be in your dependencies. Can you show your Gradle or Maven file?

Comment: @johanneslink Can I know how to find Gradle or Maven?? Those in the picture are just Java projects.